# How do I copy xml layout and preserve all the ids in it? [android]

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-studio, copy-paste

I need to make almost the same xml layout, except for some buttons, when i copy all the elements, the textviews, imageviews, buttons - all get same id! So i have to manually change the ids, i can copy 1 by 1 and each id name will be preserved.

But i am a programmer! Is there way to automate it, do it faster, more efficient?

example here , i copied half of the elements and they changed their ids automatically:
[image: dd]

Comment: What do you mean all get same id? If you just copy/paste the xml content isn't enough? Also, since you are copying things to a new xml file there is no need to use different ids than the original.

Comment: You could just re-use **the same** layout. By simply changing some Views to be **gone** or **visible**. You really don't need **duplicates**.

Comment: @jrsall92, i m making localized version of same activity, dont' ask me why i can't do it regular way in android studio, i have to do it this way - copy everything , preserver the ids, and change only the number of textViews and change their values(since it is other language)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, no , i can't do this, i m localizing same layout, replacing textviews' values

Comment: @ERJAN doesn't matter. Ids are localized only in the given xml. You can just inflate each xml when you need it.

Comment: @jrsall92, you still dont' get it, i m doing a separate application! i dont reload different xml layouts based on user's choice of language, i really need ALMOST same layout but in a different app!

Answer (score 0):

the answer is pretty simple actually: just switch to text tab in android studio, copy the actual xml code and paste it wherever you need, this way when you switch back to "design" mode - you will see all the ids in place!